# PHP backtrace dumps infinite string

Tags: php, opencart, debug-backtrace

I am debugging an odd error in order to diagnose a simplistic PHP function that is not executing properly. The function itself is not the issue. When I ran a backtrace using debug_print_backtrace(), it just keeps printing and printing, endlessly. Is a backtrace supposed to perform like this?

The site itself is Opencart v1.5.4.1, hosted on a dedicated Linux box running CentOS latest version. What else would I need to provide in order to properly diagnose? I've not run into something like this before, thus, very confused and not sure where to turn. Google search provides nothing in the way of clarity. Any ideas?

Comment: `debug_print_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS, 100);`

Comment: Doh! Thanks, Mark. Any references you're aware of that could explain the infinite output generated without those arguments? Nothing coming up on Google when I search, perhaps, not using the correct terminology to find...

Comment: recursive object nesting is the most likely, particularly with large objects